# Ajuste em gráficos com charjs

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, chartjs

Bom dia pessoal, tenho um gráfico que possui uma variável com 100 valores, porém quando o `chartJs` vai exibir ele abstrai e exibe menos pontos do que deveria, fazendo que que o gráfico fique meio quebrado como na imagem:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém o cliente não que que seja exibido todos os valores como nos `labels` do eixo `x`, mas quer que seja feita uma curva suave, segundo ele os 100 valores garantem essa curva, porém não consigo ajusta isso.

Segue o codigo do meu grafico:

```
 var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        labels: [@Session["eixox"]],
                        datasets: [{
                            label: "Probability Density Function",
                            type: "line",
                            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                            data: [@Session["eixoy1"]],
                            fill: false,

                        }]
                    }, options: {
                        elements: {
                            point: {
                                radius: 0
                            }
                        }
                    }



                });
```

Comment: Para essa curva ficar mais suave você precisa aumentar o `eixo y` colocando mais valores . É ele que deixa a curva "menos suave". Está com intervalo de 0.05 em 0.05... Experimente colocar em 0.02

Comment: Como consigo alterar isso no eixo y? o ideal pra mim seria colocar valores milesimais

Comment: Depois dê uma olhada nas escalas... Pode ser que ajude > https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/axes.html